# Ultra limit of sequence is bounded implies sequence is bounded, analogous to convergence

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, filters

Fix a non principal ultra filter $\omega$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Assume $(a_n)_n\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \omega}a_n <\infty$. Does it follow that $(a_n)_n$ is bounded by a finite value?

Comments: Put $a=\lim_{n\rightarrow \omega} a_n$. For $\epsilon=1$, consider $S_1= \{n: |a_n-a|<1\}$.

Then, $\omega(S_1)=1$ and $S_1$ is infinite. Hence for all $n\in S_1$, $|a_n|\leq |a|+1$

Thus it remains to show that $\mathbb{N}\backslash S_1$ is finite.

Comment:

Clearly, $\omega(N\backslash S_1)=0$, but this does not imply that $\mathbb{N}\backslash S_1$ is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not follow.

Take a non-principal ultrafilter $\omega$  on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega(2 \mathbb{N}) = 1$ and consider the sequence $x_n$ defined by
$x_{2n} = 0$ and $x_{2n+1} = 2n+1$. Clearly $x_n$ is unbounded and yet its $\omega$-limit is $0$.

In fact, since every non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ contains either the set of odd numbers or the set of even numbers, this idea shows that an example of this type exists for every choice of $\omega$.